# C++: How to replace single backslash with double backslash within pathnames?

Tags: c++, path, escaping, backslash

I read pathnames from an input-file using `strtok()`.
Then, within my program, I will get a `char[]` containing these pathnames, for example:

```
"C:\docs\technical-manuals\printer\Brother_4155_manual.pdf"
```

Obviously, I cannot use this within the C++ source code to open the file, because notoriously the backslash has a special meaning in C++. So I had to escape the special meaning adding a second `\`.

But it's not as simple as I thought to replace all `\` with `\\\`.

1st idea I had is to read each single char of the pathname and, while doing this, I replace any detected `\` with `\\\`, and write this to a `char[]` (or a string), e.g. `PathName[]`.

This results in getting `PathName` equals `"C:\\docs\\technical-manuals\\printer\\Brother_4155_manual.pdf"`

And using this I can open the file:

```
std::ifstream ifs;
ifs.open (PathName, std::ifstream::in)
…
```

But this is much work to do.

2nd idea is I can already write any path with two backslashes into the input-file. That's a boring work, much rather I want my program to do this.

3rd idea is I also could write `/` instead of `\\` into my input-file:

```
"C:/docs/technical-manuals/printer/Brother_4155_manual.pdf"
```

And then within my source code I replace all `/` with `\\`.

But replacing `\` with `/` in the input file is also somewhat laborious.

Does somebody know a smart and reliable solution for my "backslash replace problem"?

(Tiny remark: I’m not using Visual Studio, I'm using a special C++ compiler where the target system is not a PC. So there is only basic C++ available, no special enhancements like C++20, or boost lib, etc)

Comment: Escaped backslashes are necessary in string literals but the result is a string with a single backslash in it. If you are reading a pathname from a file that has single backslashes in it you can just use that string.

Comment: And when you do want to embed these paths in your program's code, you can use [Raw String Literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

Comment: You shouldn't need to do any of that. If you read in correct pathnames, then you don't need to add or change anything before using them. Escaping backslashes is only for  strings that you type directly into the program in a *string literal*.

Comment: _"But replacing \ with / in the input file is also somewhat laborious._" - [`std::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) ?

Comment: Look towards the [raw lines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)